# What does 之 mean in 邓小平之所以推动改革开放...?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence:

> 三十年前，邓小平**之**所以推动改革开放，一来是为了提高人民的生活水平，二来是为了让中国经济从计划经济转变到市场经济。

I found that [邓小平](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%82%93%E5%B0%8F%E5%B9%B3/116181) is a name for a person. But I don't understand what 之 works for here. So what is the meaning of it and how does it function here grammatically?

Also, is it required to use 之 here, or if you omit it, does the sentence change into a different meaning?

Comment: （see dictionaries) 之所以  the reason why    之 III
(1) 的 [of]。＂the reason why DXP has promoted reform and openness to the outside world"

Comment: @user6065 Actually I don't understand most of your comments to my question... What is `III`, `(1)`, `的`, and `[of]`? At least I've found out now that 之所以 is an idiom here, which I didn't know.

Comment: @user6065 You obviously have the answer...Why you prefer comments than adding an answer.

Comment: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Stating_the_effect_before_the_cause

Comment: answering comment #2: ＂III (1) 的 [of]＂ is copied from bkrs' (dictionary)  entry for 之（small part of long entry)

Comment: @user6065 Could you take a step further and write it up as an answer? I could get you +25 rep (and BTW why do you always leave comments here but never answer...)?

Comment: the most common use of 之 is as substitute for 的, often making it sound more official (in other cases it is obligatory), "III (1) 的 [of]" in bkrs means part III, subsection (1) of possible meanings of 之

Answer (score 2, accepted):

所以 means 'because' but it can also be used as a noun for "reason" , as in "不明所以" (don't understand the reason)

> 邓小平 is a noun,  之=(的),  所以=reason
>
> 邓小平(之)所以 = Deng Xiaoping('s) reason (for)

- 推动改革开放 (promote reform and opening up) is the action that the reason resulted in.
- 一来是为了提高人民的生活水平，二来是为了让中国经济从计划经济转变到市场经济。 is the description of the reasons

'[之所以](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/18291/)' is a common phrase for '**the reason why**'; '**therefore**' because it is so commonly used in literary form.

Example:

"(The reason why) he resigns" = "他(之所以)辭職"

"(The reason why) he ran away" = "他(之所以)逃跑"

*The two examples above must be followed by the description of the reason*

Comment: Subject always precede 之所以 in Chinese; The opposite is true in English.他(之所以)辞职 = (The reason why) he resigns

Answer (score 1):

In structure 之所以……（结果:result）是因为……（原因: reason）, 之 is used as a conjunction, indicating 因果关系.

Compare the two structures:

> 1. 之所以……（结果: result）是因为……（原因: reason)
> 2. 因为……（原因: reason）所以……（结果: result）

Structure 1 states the result first, while structure 2 states reason first. There could be some literary effects for this:

1. when there are more than one reason for the result, structure 1 is often used. This is like OP's example.
2. the context determines whether structure 1 or 2 should be used.